# Sqlite: get Count and Max of children in second tables

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I got two tables in Sqlite on an Android device where the foreign key on table 'images' is the sector_id. Now I need to queries:

1. List all sectors with the corresponding count of all rows in table images that have the sector._id
2. List all sectors with the highest ID of the images table where the sector_id is same as sector._id

For the first query the result should be like this:

- _id: 1, name:sector1, count(images):3
- _id: 2, name:sector2, count(images):2

For the second query this:

- _id: 1, name:sector1, max(images):3
- _id: 2, name:sector2, max(images):5

Hopefully you can help me on the SQL select statement :(

[image]

Comment: [Help says](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions asking for code must *demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved*. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple JOIN with GROUP BY can get both results at once;

```
SELECT s._id, s.name, COUNT(i._id) count, MAX(i._id) max
FROM sector s
LEFT JOIN images i ON s._id = i.sector_id
GROUP BY s._id, s.name
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/63f1a4/2).

The `LEFT JOIN` joins all sectors with the corresponding images, and `COUNT/MAX` calculate the count and max id respectively for each sector (which is what we group by).

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. Meanwhile I wrote a SELECT like this: SELECT sector._id, sector.name, (SELECT count(images._id) FROM route WHERE images.sector = sector._id) AS cnt FROM sector. This works for MAX too. Your solution is much better.